# Using sql average with date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large horse race database that I want to interrogate.

What I would like to do is create a new column (Average Turf Speed) to find a horse’s average speed (over the last 1 year only) prior to that day’s race and for a specific race type (Turf).

I used to do this in excel using the averageifs formular but with this much data the program would freeze and hang all the time so im planning to make the move to sql.

I’ve taken a very small sample and simplified it for demonstration purposes, I know it will contain lots of nulls but hopefully your understand my issue.

So for example if we look at Aazif in the last race on 21-05-2015 his average speed prior to that days race we would ignore the 1st race because its out of the date range and the wrong race type but we would take the 70 and 40 from the 2nd and 3rd race to give us an average of 55

```
Date and time       Horse    Race Type  Speed Rating  Average Turf Speed
10/05/2013 14:00    Aazif    AW         60  
10/05/2013 14:00    Bix      AW         50  
10/05/2013 14:00    Camelot  AW         40  
15/08/2014 15.00    Aazif    Turf       70  
15/08/2014 15.00    Bix      Turf       60  
15/08/2014 15.00    Camelot  Turf       50  
17/05/2015 13.00    Aazif    Turf       40  
17/05/2015 13.00    Bix      Turf       30  
17/05/2015 13.00    Camelot  Turf       20  
21/05/2015 14.00    Aazif    Turf       50         
21/05/2015 14.00    Bix      Turf       40  
21/05/2015 14.00    Camelot  Turf       30
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help me, Ive still not had any success solving this problem :(

Here is a link to a csv file with just over 1 year of data, ive removed all unnecessary columns to save space. hopefully this will make the problem more easier to solve.

So just to recap i want to create a new column(average turf speed) with each row showing a horses average turf speed prior to the race date and only going back 1 year before the race date.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/57dtqyhaf7cucn2/Horserace.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your definition of "large database" is large for the database engine. Usually I would do this with a more efficient left join, but you give a difficult criteria of "prior to that day’s race" that makes it difficult to write it that way. So I have one below that gives you what you want, but might have performance problems because the subquery that makes up the last column ([Prev Speed Rating]) will fire for each row. If it is slow, first try putting on a compound index made out of the columns that are used in the where clause.

```
    create view vHorseResults
    as
    select a.Horse, 
    a.[Race Type], 
    a.[Speed Rating],
    a.[date and time], 
        (select avg(b.[Speed Rating]) 
         from Races b 
         where a.Horse = b.Horse 
          and a.[Race Type] = b.[Race Type]
          and a.[date and time] > b.[date and time]
          and b.[date and time] >= dateadd(year, -1, getdate()) 
             as [Prev Speed Rating] 
    from Races a


    -- show 1 years worth of data.
        select * 
        from vHorseResults
        where getdate() >= datediff(year,-1,[date and time])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg([turf speed]) 
where 
    [date and time] between [date and time] 
    and datediff(d,-365,[date and time])
    and type='turf'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Horse, [Race Type], avg([turf speed]) 
from table 
where [date and time] >= DateAdd(yy, -1, GetDate())
group by Horse, [Race Type]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
--create temp table for data sample
DECLARE @yourdata AS TABLE
    (
      [Date and time] DATETIME ,
      Horse NVARCHAR(30) ,
      [Race Type] NVARCHAR(30) ,
      [Speed Rating] FLOAT
    )
INSERT  INTO @yourdata
        ( [Date and time], Horse, [Race Type], [Speed Rating] )
VALUES  ( '2013-05-10 14:00:00', 'Aazif', 'AW', 60 ),
        ( '2013-05-10 14:00:00', 'Bix', 'AW', 50 ),
        ( '2013-05-10 14:00:00', 'Camelot', 'AW', 40 ),
        ( '2014-05-15 15:00:00', 'Aazif', 'Turf', 70 ),
        ( '2014-05-15 15:00:00', 'Bix', 'Turf', 60 ),
        ( '2014-05-15 15:00:00', 'Camelot', 'Turf', 50 ),
        ( '2015-05-17 13:00:00', 'Aazif', 'Turf', 40 ),
        ( '2015-05-17 13:00:00', 'Bix', 'Turf', 30 ),
        ( '2015-05-17 13:00:00', 'Camelot', 'Turf', 20 ),
        ( '2015-05-21 14:00:00', 'Aazif', 'Turf', 50 ),
        ( '2015-05-21 14:00:00', 'Bix', 'Turf', 40 ),
        ( '2015-05-21 14:00:00', 'Camelot', 'Turf', 30 )  

--Final query
--1. Ignore the last race
--2. Ignore the race with wrong race type

SELECT  T.Horse ,
        AVG(T.[Speed Rating]) AS [Average Turf Speed]
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Y.Horse, Y.[Race Type] ORDER BY Y.[Date and time] DESC ) AS RN
          FROM      @yourdata AS Y
        ) AS T
WHERE   T.[Race Type] = 'Turf'
        AND T.RN <> 1
GROUP BY T.Horse
```

*output*

[image]

if required to get average in one year range from the last not ignored race, use this:

```
--Final query
--1. Ignore the last race
--2. Ignore the race with wrong race type
--3. get average in one year range from the last not ignored race

SELECT  Y.Horse ,
        AVG(Y.[Speed Rating]) AS [Average Turf Speed]
FROM    ( SELECT    * ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Y.Horse, Y.[Race Type] ORDER BY Y.[Date and time] DESC ) AS RN ,
                    MAX(Y.[Date and time]) OVER ( PARTITION BY Y.Horse,
                                                  Y.[Race Type] ) AS newlast
          FROM      @yourdata AS Y
        ) Y
WHERE   CONVERT(DATE, Y.[Date and time]) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(YEAR,
                                                              -1, Y.newlast))
                                         AND     CONVERT(DATE, Y.newlast)
        AND Y.RN <> 1
        AND Y.[Race Type] = 'Turf'
GROUP BY Y.Horse
```

*output*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table table
(
    [DateTime] datetime,
    Horse varchar(20),
    RaceType varchar(40),
    Speed int
)


INSERT @Table VALUES
(CONVERT(datetime, '10/05/2013 14:00',103),'Aazif','AW','60'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '10/05/2013 14:01',103),'Bix','AW','50'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '10/05/2013 14:02',103),'Camelot','AW','40'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '15/08/2014 15:00',103),'Aazif','Turf','70'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '15/08/2014 15:00',103),'Bix','Turf','60'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '15/08/2014 15:00',103),'Camelot','Turf','50'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '17/05/2015 13:00',103),'Aazif','Turf','40'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '17/05/2015 13:00',103),'Bix','Turf','30'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '17/05/2015 13:00',103),'Camelot','Turf','20'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '21/05/2015 14:00',103),'Aazif','Turf','50'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '21/05/2015 14:00',103),'Bix','Turf','40'),
(CONVERT(datetime, '21/05/2015 14:00',103),'Camelot','Turf','30')

SELECT 
    *
FROM    
    @Table data
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT AVG(Speed) AS AverageSpeedOfPreviousYear 
        FROM @Table 
        WHERE 
            [DateTime] < data.[DateTime] 
            AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, [DateTime], data.DateTime) <= 1 
            AND Horse = data.Horse 
            AND RaceType = data.RaceType
    ) avg
```

**Result**

```
DateTime                Horse                RaceType Speed       AverageSpeedOfPreviousYear
----------------------- -------------------- -------- ----------- --------------------------
2013-05-10 14:00:00.000 Aazif                AW       60          NULL
2013-05-10 14:01:00.000 Bix                  AW       50          NULL
2013-05-10 14:02:00.000 Camelot              AW       40          NULL
2014-08-15 15:00:00.000 Aazif                Turf     70          NULL
2014-08-15 15:00:00.000 Bix                  Turf     60          NULL
2014-08-15 15:00:00.000 Camelot              Turf     50          NULL
2015-05-17 13:00:00.000 Aazif                Turf     40          70
2015-05-17 13:00:00.000 Bix                  Turf     30          60
2015-05-17 13:00:00.000 Camelot              Turf     20          50
2015-05-21 14:00:00.000 Aazif                Turf     50          55
2015-05-21 14:00:00.000 Bix                  Turf     40          45
2015-05-21 14:00:00.000 Camelot              Turf     30          35
```